# Detecting AUv3 invalidations in a host app (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, swift, audiounit, auv3

I'm working on a AUv3 host app, and I want the users to be notified when a loaded audio unit crashes (gets invalidated) for some reason. I looked at Apple's documentations about AUAudioUnit, but couldn't find any information about how to detect an invalidation of an audio unit (AUv3) from the host app.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can catch the `kAudioComponentInstanceInvalidationNotification` and act accordingly.. which is usually a restart of the host app.

Comment: Thanks so much @OI . That worked flawlessly:)))

Answer (score 2):

when setting up your AudioEngine you can observe `kAudioComponentInstanceInvalidationNotification` to figure out if its audio component instance was invalidated later on.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserverForName:kAudioComponentInstanceInvalidationNotification object:nil queue:nil usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {

    AUAudioUnit *auUnit = (AUAudioUnit *)note.object;

    NSValue *val = note.userInfo[@"audioUnit"];
    AudioUnit auAddress = (AudioUnit)val.pointerValue;

    NSLog(@"AudioComponent Invalidation of Unit:%@ with Address:%p", auUnit, auAddress);

}];
```

keep in mind that you may have got the notification but the component ended up in a deadlock. So when trying to recover from that you may have to turn down the whole host app.

Comment: Thanks again @OI. So actually this leads me to the following question. Isn't there a way to reload an AUAudioUnit, or should I simply remove the invalidated one from the audio engine, and instanciate a fresh new one?

Comment: i would say: reload is per definition invalidate & remove + instance fresh. :)

Comment: @OlSen I'm stumbling on this. My question is: how do I inform the host application that a certain audio unit has been invalidated? I can't seem to access the pointer to the host app from the notification callback and I also can't seem to pass an additional pointer to it. Can you please advise? Thanks!

Comment: the comment section will not be enough to advice, stack a question instead as this seems to be an entirely different approach depending on your host. But what comes to mind first is that notifications can not only be received but sent as well.